# Moving a VPN Tunnel from Project A to Project B - GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, vpn

I have an existing tunnel in project A. Project A is NOT a shared project (not a shared VPC). Project B IS a HOST project and has a shared VPC. I would like to move the tunnel from Project A to Project B...Is that possible or do I have to rebuild the tunnel from scratch in project B? Is there a gCloud way to set a new project ID on the tunnel?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can't move resources from a project to another one. Thus, and sadly, you can't reuse your VPN configuration and your static IP. You have to set up a new VPN in your project B, create a new IP and thus to change also the peer side of the VPN for updating the VPN.

*Note: It's not absolutely true, if you have lot of resources and if you are a large Google Cloud customer, the support can accept to move resources from a project to another one. But it's a manual process on their side and they prefer to avoid this.*